# CASE in UPDATE for choose a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, request

Hello i want to make a request to choose the column will be updated

```
UPDATE `ze_mail` SET 
        (CASE
            WHEN `ze_mail_id` = 1 AND `ze_mail_user1_id` = 27
            THEN(
                `ze_mail_user1_lastDate`
            )
            WHEN `ze_mail_id` = 1 AND `ze_mail_user2_id` = 27
            THEN(
                `ze_mail_user2_lastDate`
            )
        END) 
        = NOW()
WHERE WHEN `ze_mail_id` = 1
```

for obtaining that

```
UPDATE `ze_mail` SET `ze_mail_user1_lastDate` = NOW() WHERE `ze_mail_id` = 1
```

or that

```
UPDATE `ze_mail` SET `ze_mail_user2_lastDate` = NOW() WHERE `ze_mail_id` = 1
```

Can you help me?

Comment: A case expression returns a value, it's not about conditional execution of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just 'update' both, and use `CASE EXPRESSION` so the result won't change if it doesn't answer the condition :

```
UPDATE `ze_mail`
  SET `ze_mail_user1_lastDate` = CASE WHEN `ze_mail_user1_id` = 27
                                      THEN NOW() 
                                      ELSE `ze_mail_user1_lastDate`
                                 END,
       `ze_mail_user2_lastDate` = CASE WHEN `ze_mail_user2_id` = 27
                                      THEN NOW() 
                                      ELSE `ze_mail_user2_lastDate`
                                 END
WHERE `ze_mail_id` = 1
```

**Notes:**

`WHERE WHEN` is wrong, a simple `WHERE` is enough.

A `CASE` is an expression, it can only provide a value .

You don't need to use `ze_mail_id = 1` on the `CASE EXPRESSION` because you are filtering them already.

Comment: @BerndBuffen What?